# My Raspi speaker is saying everything I write

Tags: raspbian

Something strange is happening with my Raspi speaker.

Everything I do in Raspbian is repeated by my speaker.

For example, when I type "ls" in my terminal, it says "ls" and then tells me all the folders found in the directory.

How can I turn off this weird behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this in your terminal:

`sudo apt purge espeak`

or

`sudo apt purge orca`.

Good luck!